# java.net.ConnectException: after adding weblogic-application.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, classloader, weblogic-10.x

I have recently added weblogic-application.xml to my ear to resolve antlr jar file conflict in weblogic 10.x

```
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<prefer-application-packages>
  <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
</weblogic-application>
```

now when deploying the application I m getting the following exception:

```
Error while parsing the Tag Library Descriptor at 
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: 'java.sun.com', port: '80'
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwFromIOE(StreamScanner.java:683)
at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1086)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TldCacheHelper$TldIOHelper.parseXML(TldCacheHelper.java:134)
at weblogic.descriptor.DescriptorCache.parseXML(DescriptorCache.java:380)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TldCacheHelper.parseTagLibraries(TldCacheHelper.java:65)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

java.net.ConnectException: Tried all: '1' addresses, but could not connect over HTTP to server: 'java.sun.com', port: '80'
at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:312)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:388)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:238)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:172)
at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:356)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

This seems to be a proxy issue. Why this is happening only after adding the weblogic-application.xml?

Any solution that may not require changing the weblogic server config?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems if your .xml file has any taglib is failing to download the DTD definition from Internet because of private network. This is thread has discussion on possible work around. [Work around link](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=847256)